# heat equation maximum principle (clarification)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I have the following heat equation

Let $\Omega=\{(x,t) \;t\gt |x| \}$

and $u$ be a solution to the heat equation $$\begin{align} u_t -u_{xx}=0 &&(x,t)\in\Omega \\ u(x,t)=t &&(x,t) \in \partial \Omega \end{align}$$

The maximum principle states (in my script) that the maximum is obtained on the parabolic boundary. I am a little confused. What would be the parabolic boundary of $\Omega$ ?

Comment: $\partial \Omega$.

Comment: Related: (unanswered but relevant details in question body) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2668086/parabolic-boundary